# Skip class from UnitTest - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, visual-studio-2019

How to Skip class from unittest in visual studio 2019

ClienteRepositoryTests extends RepositoryTestBase.

RepositoryTestBase is a base for all unittests. I'd like that RepositoryTest dont show in Test Explorer

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the base class abstract.

Both XUnit and MSTest (and probably other frameworks) use reflection to find correctly decorated methods (or types) and have to instantiate them in order to run the tests.  If your class is abstract, the method will still exist on the derived type (still decorated as a test method), but the base class cannot be instantiated.